# Olingo V2.0.4 retrieve javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets, olingo

Would like to ask is there a way to retrieve the HttpServletResponse within olingo - ODataServiceFactory? This requirement is need to authenticate the user from SAP Portal using UMFactory.

At the moment I am managed to retrieve the HttpServletRequest using the following code:

```
HttpServletRequest X = (HttpServletRequest) context.getParameter(ODataContext.HTTP_SERVLET_REQUEST_OBJECT);
```

Comment: What is the type of "context" in this snippet?  Can we get at this using an ODataRequest instance in an OData EntityProcessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the right way to access the ServletRequest from within the Olingo library. Another way would be to use servlet filters. This way you get access to the ServletRequest before the Olingo library gets called and can make your authentication there. This way you can be sure that once your ServiceFactory gets called you already have an authenticated user.

Since you wrote about the ServletResponse there is no way to access that in Olingo V2 at the moment. If you have such a requirement I would suggest you take this up to the olingo users list user@olingo.apache.org
Again you can use servlet filters here to access the ServletResponse after Olingo processed it.

Here is a good tutorial on how to use servlet filters in my opinion: http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial